# substitute characters but not the last one

Tags: ruby, substitution

I have a string for example like this:

```
str = 'TEST;NAME=1;TARGET_SOMETHING;PLATFORM_INTEL;'
```

Now I would like to substitute all `";"` with `"-D"` and delete the last `";"`

I'm doing it with:

```
str.gsub(/;/, ' -D').gsub(/^/, ' -D')
```

the second `gsub` is only to add the `-D` also to the beginn of line

Result:

```
-DTEST -DNAME=1 -DTARGET_SOMETHING -DPLATFORM_INTEL -D
```

How to tell Ruby not to output the last `"-D"` or to delete the last `";"` in `str`?

Any suggestions to do it in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elements= (str.gsub(/;/, ' -D').gsub(/^/, ' -D')).split(' ')
```

output will be:

```
["-DTEST", "-DNAME=1", "-DTARGET_SOMETHING", "-DPLATFORM_INTEL", "-D"]
```

then delete last element from an array:

```
elements.delete_at(elements.size-1)
```

output will be in elements variable

```
p elements

["-DTEST", "-DNAME=1", "-DTARGET_SOMETHING", "-DPLATFORM_INTEL"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `split` and `map` for this.

```
irb(main):012:0> str.split(";").map {|i| "-D#{i}"}.join(" ")
=> "-DTEST -DNAME=1 -DTARGET_SOMETHING -DPLATFORM_INTEL"
```